# Android ConstraintLayout: vertically align/size 3 views

Tags: android

Trying to create layout to match the image:

[image]

- The bottom block starts at 90% from the top of the main view.
- The height of each row is the remaining space / 3 with an 8dp margin
  around each view.
- The squares on the left each have a 1:1 ratio, and
  the rectangles to their right match their height and fill the remaining
  space horizontally.

I start with a horizontal guideline at 90% and place 3 views vertically roughly where I want them on the left.

I select the top one and constrain it's top edge to the top of the parent. I set this to 8dp. I select the bottom one and constrain its bottom edge to the 90% guideline. I set this to 8dp.

I constrain each one's left edge to the left edge of the parent

I go into the XML and add app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" to each of the 3 views

I select all 3, right click and choose expand vertically

I select the top block, make its width and height 0dp and it shrinks to a dot

I select the middle block, make its width and height 0dp and it shrinks to a dot

I select the lower block, make its width and height 0dp and it expands to fill to the top parent

I thought at this point all the definitions would be in place for the 3 blocks to be equally sized and placed where they will finally be. In other words, even though I've then tried to continue with the remaining work, its so screwed up I'm unable to continue.

Here's the XML before the expand vertically step:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Couldn't it be easily done by using a GridLayout?

Comment: as @Rotwang said you can use GridLayout or LinearLayout to achieve what you want.

Comment: I just tried to write only the squares as in your layout, and what happens is that the bottom square is so big that eats up the space of the others

Comment: I know there are other ways to do this but I specifically want to use ConstraintLayout, thanks.

Comment: I don't think the layout as you have it would be enough as the views aren't fully constraining top/bottom to each other to form a vertical chain. However, I've tried to make this work and getting very odd behaviour, it seems like chains and ratios don't play well together.

Comment: Thank you Lewis - I'm coming to the conclusion some layouts are just not possible using only ConstraintLayout. This is the second one I've not been able to get working, the first was similar but involved 3 horizontal guidelines to which Views just would not line up. They also involved the ratiios, so there might be a clue there. I also tested using AS 3.0 preview 5, so it's not like I'm fighting early ConstraintLayotu bugs (I hope!).